# Jquery if value is minus the main value

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please how do i get this workin in Jquery? i want to achieve this using jquery need your help.. example if  35000 - 349990 = - 314990

if it show -314990 i want to display error to the user...

I came up with this didn't help...

```
$("#apaid1").keyup(function () { // apaid input id for user to enter amount
    var textinput = $('#apaid1').val(); // get value from input id apaid1
    var textinput1 = $('#epayment1').val(); // get value from input id epayment1

    $("#bl1").val("" + textinput1 - textinput);
    // input id bl1 used as output

    if ($("#bl1").val() < textinput1) {

        $("#bl1").val("" + textinput1 - textinput);
    };
});
```

This is what it gave me me -314990 i want to display error base on negative values

sorry for poor english.
Thank you very much....

Comment: Display error where?

Comment: try something along the lines of : `if(a + b < 0) {/*Do stuff */}`

Comment: display error @  `#bl1` input id

Comment: @MarshallUnduemi post your html also

Comment: `""+textinput1 - textinput` is `"string" plus "string"  minus "string"`

Comment: If you could create a JSFiddle with your code to show the problem it'd be easier to answer your question.

Comment: `var val =textinput1 - textinput;  $("#bl1").val(val); if (val < 0) $("#bl1Message").text("error");`

Comment: ok fine, i will create the JSfiddle

Comment: Get a id in your html page append that error to selected dom and then put it inside the if condion with your error

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#apaid1").keyup(function(){ 
    var textinput = $('#apaid1').val(); 
    var textinput1 = $('#epayment1').val(); 

    /* I'm assuming that the "#bl1" tag is the input where you want to store the product of "textinput" and "textinput1"? */
    $("#bl1").val(textinput1 - textinput);

    //if the value is less than zero (e.g: a negative number), send an alert to the user.
    if ($("#bl1").val() < 0) {
        alert("Hey! Your answer resulted in a negative. Try again");
    };

});
```

I'm not entirely sure why you set your condition as "if ($("#bl1").val() < textinput1) ... " and why you tried to recalculate the value when you fulfill that condition. It seems rather strange to me. So if you have a reason for doing that, or if I misunderstood your question, do elaborate.

Comment: **Aetheus** and **Asad Sheikh** it work fine  JSfiddle updated https://jsfiddle.net/marshallunduemi/gkd7yLuc/6/ thanks all of you, am so glad

Comment: See: https://jsfiddle.net/ewgwc52t/

If this is a homework assignment, I'd highly recommend that you do more study on basic JavaScript and jQuery before moving forward.

Answer (score 1):

use this condition to check the negative value.

```
 ($("#bl1").val() < 0)
```

Comment: Thank u too, really really appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have added

```
if(textinput1 - textinput < 0)
{
   alert("Error: Negative");
}
```

see your updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gkd7yLuc/8/)